# MySQL Query, remove all spaces

Tags: mysql

I have an unusual query, which got me stuck right now

Table Fields are:

```
id    bigint  20
name  varchar 255
desc  text
```

There are many records with same name and desc, but desc have some extra spaces in between words

like

```
1   't1'   'hello world'
2   't2'   'hello                world'
```

I need to find those rows that have similar data

How can I find these, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is pretty close.  Assuming:

```
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+

| Field | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| d     | text    | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| id    | int(11) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Then this query:

```
select x.id,x2.id,x.d,x2.d from x left join x as x2 on replace(x.d," ","") = replace(x2.d," ","") and x.id != x2.id having !(x2.id is null);
```

Gets you the duplicate rows.  It fails if you have "Helloworld" (i.e. with no space) and you don't want that to match.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you need to preserve the original data, something like this is best done at insertion time, when you create/update the record, rather than later, at comparison time.

That being said, you could do something like

```
SELECT id, name, desc, REPLACE(desc, '  ', ' ') as replaced
                                      xx    x  <--note the number of spaces
FROM table
GROUP replaced
HAVING replaced > 1
```

Probably won't perfectly, and you'll have to adjust the replacement portion a few times, but this should get you started.